# Creating a Playlist of Widgets

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I'm trying to create a specialized theme that would enable users to show a playlist of widgets in their sidebar. By playlist, I mean that each widget in the sidebar would follow a specific schedule. For example, one widget might be scheduled to show every day from 9AM-5PM, while another widget may be scheduled to show daily from 5PM-11PM.

Is there a way this can be done such that the scheduling of individual widgets is handled by the theme itself?

Thx.

Comment: Define "handled by theme" ? The location of code is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: I guess I'm just looking for some general guidance and a starting point, and to know if something like this is even possible in the first place. Can I manipulate the sidebar in this manner? If so, where is the best place to have someone configure the schedule for each of the widgets that are added to the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any themes that would do that, but you could create a widget that displays different content according to the time or date.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this, but what I would do:

Use a plugin that creates widgets as a custom post type, like [Custom Post Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-widget/).
Then use something like [Timed Content](http://wordpress.org/plugins/timed-content/) plugin to schedule the content that you want to appear at the relevant time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not quite what I'm looking for though. I would like to be able to use existing widgets that have already been built, and somehow tack scheduling information onto them.